# Linux - display memory of some command

Tags: python, linux, command

I want to display memory (RAM) of some commmand in Linux. For example, I write to command line this command - for run Python script:

```
python 'someScript.py'
```

I want to display how much memory this command (process) uses.

Comment: if this command runs for more than a few milliseconds you may use the command "top" while it is running in another terminal window.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'time' command

```
/usr/bin/time -v python 'someScript.py'
```

*note that this is not a built-in shell command*

Answer (score 1):

there are many commands that you can use:

```
proc/meminfo
top
htop
```

among this command I think `top` is suitable for you, top clearly highlights which processes are consuming the most CPU cycles and memory

Answer (score 1):

```
ps aux | grep "myscrip_name" | awk '{print $4}'
```

To display the % of memory being used by the running process `myscript_name`. Obviously can get the memory used when you know the % used.